# How can I adjust the position of a label for a zend form Radio element?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

with this piece of code

```
$feOnline = New Zend_Form_Element_Radio('online');
$feOnline->setValue($article->online)
        ->addMultiOptions(array(0=>'offline', 1=>'online'))
        ->setLabel('Online');
```

this html is generated

```
<dd id="online-element">
<label for="online-0">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" id="online-0" name="online">offline
</label><br>
<label for="online-1"><input type="radio" value="1" id="online-1" name="online">online
</label>
</dd>
```

However I don't want the input-tag inside the label-tag. No need for the "
" either...

What decorators must I add to get this output?

```
<dd id="online-element">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" id="online-0" name="online"><label for="online-0">offline</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id="online-1" name="online"><label for="online-1">online</label>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using default `Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio` you can't change the way radio is rendered.
The code is as follows (line 159)

```
// Wrap the radios in labels
$radio = '<label'
        . $this->_htmlAttribs($label_attribs) . ' for="' . $optId . '">'
        . (('prepend' == $labelPlacement) ? $opt_label : '')
        . '<input type="' . $this->_inputType . '"'
        . ' name="' . $name . '"'
        . ' id="' . $optId . '"'
        . ' value="' . $this->view->escape($opt_value) . '"'
        . $checked
        . $disabled
        . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
        . $endTag
        . (('append' == $labelPlacement) ? $opt_label : '')
        . '</label>';
```

No configuration is in place to change the logic.
Think of the reason why you **REALLY** need to change the way it is rendered, try using CSS to style the output for example.
If you conclude, you *need* to change rendering, create your own view helper and use it instead of the default one.